Disable row resizing on datagridview c#
I wounder how to disable or prevent users from resizing Datagridview Rows and also disable the click on the horizontal line of the rows.
I have tried setting the DataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows to false. It didn't work !
any help please I'm stuck for more than a week now.


DataGridView.RowTemplate.Resizable = false;.

